# How can i combine two update requests into one?

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js, nodes

I now have a code that works.

```
await Users.update({ selected: false }, { where: { userId: req.body.userId } });
await Users.update(
  {
    selected: req.body.selected,
    descr: req.body.note
  },
  {
    where:
    {
      entId: req.body.id,
      userId: req.body.userId
    }
  }
);
```

But what if it is possible to combine these two queries into one? I need the 'selected' and 'note' field that I pass to change conditionally in the table. And all other 'selected' fields inherent to the user in the table became false.
Unfortunately, I did not find anything like that in the documentation. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such method like `bulkUpdate` in Sequelize so you need to call `update` twice and better to use a transaction to make these two queries as a one atomic operation.

```
await Sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
  await Users.update({ selected: false }, { where: { userId: req.body.userId }, transaction });
  await Users.update(
    {
      selected: req.body.selected,
      descr: req.body.note
    },
    {
      where:
      {
        entId: req.body.id,
        userId: req.body.userId
      },
      transaction
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sequelize `transaction` and wrap it up inside try/catch,

```
// define transaction outside the try/catch so you can rollback if needed
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

try {

await Users.update({ selected: false }, { where: { userId: req.body.userId }, transaction })
    .then((r) => r)
    .catch((e) => {
        throw e;
    });

await Users.update(
    {
        selected: req.body.selected,
        descr: req.body.note
    },
    {
        where: {
            entId: req.body.id,
            userId: req.body.userId
        },
        transaction
    }
    )
    .then((r) => r)
    .catch((e) => {
        throw e;
    });

  // always call commit at the end
  await transaction.commit();
  return true;

 } catch (error) {
   // always rollback
   await transaction.rollback();
   console.log(error);
   throw error;
 }
```